# Convert MySQL group concat string to json object structure via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, concatenation, group-concat

I have 2 MySQL tables, the first one is the parent table and second one the child table. These two table share a **1:M relationship**. The `T_1` contains the list of unique users with some informations. And the `T_2` contains all the line data list with coordinates at a specific timestamp for each user. The child table `T_2` has a **FK** that references the **PK** in the `T_1` parent table. I share below the CREATE STATEMENT:

```
CREATE TABLE `T_1` (
  `id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value_1` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `personId` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `value_2` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `value_3` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Value_4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`personId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `T_2` (
  `personId` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `user_fk_idx` (`personId`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`personId`) REFERENCES `T_1` (`personId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I would like to get as final json result something like that:

```
[
    {
        "id": "",
        "value_1": true,
        "personId": "1",
        "value_2": "test",
        "value_3": "test",
        "value_4": 10,
        "lineData": [
            {
                "timestamp": "some_date",
                "x": 100,
                "y": 250
            },
            {
                "timestamp": "some_date",
                "x": 100,
                "y": 350
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "value_1": true,
        "personId": "2",
        "value_2": "test",
        "value_3": "test",
        "value_4": 10,
        "lineData": [
            {
                "timestamp": "some_date",
                "x": 50,
                "y": 450
            },
            {
                "timestamp": "some_date",
                "x": 80,
                "y": 550
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the first query selection that I have made in order to get the aggregation of all the `T_2` records for each `T_1.personId`:

```
SELECT T_1.personId,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(T_2.timestamp, T_2.x, T_2.y) SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM T_1 
JOIN T_2
ON T_1.personId=T_2.personId 
GROUP  BY personId;
```

Except that I need to add also `id`, `value_1`, `value_2`, `value_3`, `value_4`, the query aggregation seems correct by I'm still far away from the expected result:

[image]

By using the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`query fetch within PHP I get actually the similar expected array result.

**But the main problem is that the linedata aggregation is just in a single string format grouped and concatenated all together, not in an object structure form. (screen below)**

[image]

I attach the example data below from the query selection:

```
array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    NULL
    ["value_1"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["personId"]=>
    string(2) "1"
    ["value_2"]=>
    string(9) "test"
    ["value_3"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["value_4"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["linedata"]=>
    string(359) "2018/09/15 10:00:05 AM1100950 2018/09/15 10:00:07 AM1100850 2018/09/15 10:00:09 AM1180800 2018/09/15 10:00:10 AM1280800 2018/09/15 10:00:15 AM1380800 2018/09/15 10:00:17 AM1480800 2018/09/15 10:00:20 AM1900800 2018/09/15 10:00:25 AM1930750 2018/09/15 10:00:40 AM1910440 2018/09/15 10:00:45 AM1250460 2018/09/15 10:01:25 AM1100455 2018/09/15 10:01:29 AM1100655"
  }
}
```

Maybe is it needed to concatenate the square and curly brackets within the selection query?

Can someone suggest me how to get the correct separated structure for linea data? I supposed that we need to use also some post-process PHP stuff in order to get the exact desired output structure.

#### Update

Following the @Salman A's suggestion, I have tweak the query as below:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(', ',timestamp,x, y) SEPARATOR '; ') as linedata_0
```

And I have stored the result of the query within `$query_result`.
Then I have made a nested foreach in order to explode each row with `;` and each value of each row with `,` in `$query_result['linedata_0']`. And I have put the exploded result in a new key called `linedata_1`. As showed below:

```
foreach ($query_result as $q_r){
        $first_split = explode(";", $q_r["linedata_0"]);
        foreach ($first_split as $f_s){
            $second_split =   explode(",", $f_s);          
            $query_result["linedata_1"][]= $second_split;         
        }       
  }
```

I have removed the `$query_result[0]["linedata_0"]` element. And after that I have assigned the key values to each `$query_result['linedata_1']` sub-arrays and store in a new element called `$query_result['linedata']`. After that I have remove the old `$query_result['linedata_1']` element with `unset` command and in the last foreach I have cast the `x` and `y` values from string to integer:

```
unset($query_result[0]["linedata_0"]);
   
foreach(($query_result["linedata_1"]) as $q_r) {

    $keys = array('timestamp', 'x', 'y');
    
    $query_result["linedata"][] = array_combine($keys, $q_r);
}
   
unset($query_result["linedata_1"]);

$index = 0;
foreach($query_result["linedata"] as $index=>$val) {
    
    $query_result["linedata"][$index]["x"] = (int) $val["x"];
    $query_result["linedata"][$index]["y"] = (int) $val["y"];
    
    $index++;
}
```

With these PHP post-process operations **I got exactly the expected result**.Probably this post-process steps within php are not well optimized, but they do the trick for me. If someone of us has a more optimized workaround solution please share it. Thanks.

Comment: You should include example data also.. (INSERTS)

Comment: @RaymondNijland Do you mean the output of the selection query?

Comment: Why do you want to do this via MySQL instead of PHP?

Comment: i mean the example data (table data) for the expected  json result

Comment: @SalmanA also with PHP is okay.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have put the CREATE STMT, but if is needed I can also share the 2 tables with some data example filled.

Comment: @UgoL if you got that array in PHP then all you need to do is call `json_encode` on that array. You can tweak the query that generates `linedata` and use `,` to separate fields and `;` to separate rows, and use `explode` and `array_map` function in PHP to convert it into array of arrays (which could be fed to json encode).

Comment: @SalmanA Can you provide me as answer a quick example of how to "tweak" the current query for linedata in order to separate correctly each grouped row, and the explode/map process via PHP?

Comment: @SalmanA I have updated my question with a work-around solution following your suggestions. Let me know what you think please and if you have a better optimized solution let me know. Thanks..

Comment: @UgoL your code is OK if it is getting you desired result. Optimize only if you find it slow. I could simply write it in my own way (using as many array functions I know of as possible) and call it "optimized" when it really isn't.

Comment: @UgoL mine is just a personal consideration... your code is **not correct at all**. Cause you are getting the desired result for just one object, *personId=1*. But what about if you have more than one, as in the case of *personId=2*? You need for sure to correct the `foreach` statement.